# Как в Intellij IDEA добавить dependency в pom.xml

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Вопрос, может быть, покажется и глупым, но у меня не получается ...!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой проект. При deploy выскакивает ошибка:

> "Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
>   for: java.util.Set, at table: Files, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(columns)]"

В сущности в "File.java" есть поле:

```
private Set<FileColumn> columns;
```

Так вот мне показалось, что нужно добавить что-то типа:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Простым добавлением в "pom.xml" в секцию dependecies у меня не получилось. При компиляции Maven говорит:

> "'dependencies.dependency.version' for
>   org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar is missing"

Вопрос: как добавить (и самое главное куда именно) этот jar-ник? Опишите последовательность манипуляций в IDEA. Пожалуйста!!!

Answer (score 3):

ошибка возникает потому что вы не указали версию:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: прошу прощения, что не отписался... да, верно, я уже сам пофиксил...
теперь возникает ошибка при компиляции maven-ом CSV_Client модуля: "compilation error cannot find symbol"

Дело в том, что в File.java есть класс "File", а в Container.java есть ф-ция с параметром типа File. Лог с ошибкой говорит, что он не понимает этого класса File. Они же находятся в одном пакете, так почему возникает ошибка?

Comment: это уже тема для отдельного вопроса, если добавите стактрейс ошибки, - разберемся

Comment: спасибо за предложение, но уже разобрался... нужно было в pom-ник модуля CSV_Client добавить dependency на модуль CSV!